# Use of variable in mkdir command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a variable with `mkdir` but it does not create a new directory. If I try without the variable it works fine.

```
[kurs@localhost ~]$ K="~/a/`date +%Y%m%d`"
[kurs@localhost ~]$ echo $K
~/a/20190926
[kurs@localhost ~]$ mkdir $K
mkdir: nie można utworzyć katalogu „~/a/20190926”: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
[kurs@localhost ~]$ 
[kurs@localhost ~]$ mkdir ~/a/20190926
```

Comment: Use `LANG=C mkdir $K` before post output!

Comment: Prefer using "$HOME" instead of `~` in such cases. Also if `a` doesn't exist yet in your home dir, pass `-p` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the `mkdir` command, but the variable assignment. `~` is only expanded to your home directory if you leave it unquoted. If you quote it you get a literal tilde character. Leave out the double quotes.

```
$ K=~/a/`date +%Y%m%d`
$ echo $K
/home/kurs/a/20190926
$ mkdir $K
```

It's a good idea to quote variable expansions or else file names with spaces and other unusual characters will mess you up. I recommend you write:

```
$ mkdir "$K"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "a" directory doesn't exist. Use the command with -p option `mkdir -p $K`. It will create all missing intermediate directories. 
Update: as per Mihir suggestion - "~" will be treated as the name for a new directory, it won't use HOME directory as parent for "a", to avoid it set your K variable using $HOME instead of "~".